# Foreign Key in SQL table?

Tags: sql, key

In some book i came across this 'categories' table, and i don't know what is the last 2 lines about. I don't know if it's a foreign key or sth else. Help much appreciated. Noteworthy that cat_parent_id and cat_name aren't mentioned anywhere else in other tables in the application.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'categories' (
    'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    'parent_id' int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    'name' varchar(50) character NOT NULL,
    'description' varchar (200) character NOT NULL,
    'image' varchar(255) character NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    KEY 'cat_parent_id' ('parent_id'),
    KEY 'cat_name' ('name')
    );
```

Comment: Which DBMS? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: No idea, have to search it

Comment: well cat_parent_id and cat_name aren't mentioned anywhere else because they refer to parent_id and name which are in this table. This is probably Complex foreign key created with 2 fields (parent_id, name) to make hierarchy in categories.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be MySQL syntax with single quotes mixed up for back ticks.  If you attempted to run this code, you would get an error.  However, I will assume that the single quotes are really back ticks (although they are not needed at all).

The `key` keyword in MySQL builds an index on the column(s) in the expression.  This is a shorthand way of saying:

```
create index cat_parent_id on categories(parent_id);
create index cat_name on categories(name);
```

It is handy because the statement is part of the `create table` statement, rather than being a separate statement.

It is equivalent to the keyword `index` in this context, and most databases support some method for doing this (although not necessarily the `key` keyword).